# Titanium mobile relative layout

Tags: android, layout, titanium, fill-parent

I'm creating android app using Titanium mobile.
How do I create this interface using vertical layout?

```
----------------
Header View        } height = 40dp
-----------------


 Content View      } height = fill_parent


----------------
```

In the official android sdk, we have fill_parent size to stretch the content view to bottom. Setting height to 'auto' will adjust the height according the height of the content; setting it to '100%' will covers the whole screen.

Been searching this answer for days, really appreciate your helps.

**Edit:**
Another question, what if the header view was at bottom?

```
-----------------


 Content View      } height = fill_parent


----------------
 Header View        } height = 40dp
----------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content view should be like this (like you also can do it with HTML)

```
var content_view = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 40,
    bottom: 0
});
```

If the bar is at the bottom, just turn it around:

```
var content_view = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    bottom: 40
});
```

Comment: thank you, but what if the header view was at bottom? (added to my original question)

Comment: turn it around :) That easy :) Added it to my answer